# jQuery Validation dependent rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form which should be validated using "if...else if" logic. My actual form is bit more complicated than this but the implementation is similar to this example.

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
<form>
    <input name="input" type="text" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$.validator.addMethod("equals1", function(value, element, param)
{
    return value == 1;
}, "The value entered should be 1");

$.validator.addMethod("equals2", function(value, element, param)
{
    return value == 2;
}, "The value entered should be 2");

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        input: {
            required: true,
            equals1: true,
            equals2: true
        }
    }
});
```

I want the equals2 rule to be implemented only if equals1 rule is false like below

```
if (value == 1)
    return true;
else if (value == 2)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

I can't combine both the rules into one because I want different error messages for different scenarios.

Comment: Okay, so what have you done to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Also, your description makes no logical sense.  If the `equals1` rule is false validation fails, end of story.  Does not matter what happens with `equals2` rule at this point.

Comment: @Sparky My intention is to not stop validating if one rule fails. Even if equals1 fails, it should move onto the next rule. I can combine the rules but I want different checks to spit out different error messages. The "addMethod" allows to specify just one error message which I want to customise depending on the checks

Comment: Does not work like that. If a rule fails, then validation stops until that rule is satisfied.

Comment: Lets see if anyone has some ideas. If not, I will close this question and will go with custom validation

Comment: [I’ve answered over 1600 questions about this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a594235%20%5bjquery-validate%5d%20is%3aanswer), so I’ll be pretty interested in seeing that too.  But there is a way to have multiple/dynamic messages within a single custom method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question started off wanting dependent rules but the purpose behind it is to have "if...else if" type validation and different conditions spitting out different error messages. Here is how I achieved it.

```
$.validator.addMethod("equalsCheck", function(value, element, param)
{
    if (value == 1)
        return true;
    else if (value == 2)
        return true;
    return false;
}, 
function(){
    if ($("input").val()=="12")
    return "Value should not be 12 but 1 or 2";
    else if($("input").val()!="1" && $("input").val()!="2")
    return "Value must be equal to either 1 or 2";
    return "";
});
```

In the addMethod, instead of passing just string (*error message*) for the 3rd parameter, pass a function object which returns the error message that you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/vidhyardhi/kjv6kotg/